# Different in List size

Tags: python, list, size

could someone explain me the difference in the List **size**? Once it is (x,1) and the other (x,). I think I get an idexError due to that.

Thanks
[image]

```
print(Annotation_Matrix)
   [array([[1],
   ..., 
   [7],
   [7],
   [7]], dtype=uint8)]

print(idx)
[array([ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False], dtype=bool)]
```

p.s. the left one is created with

```
matlabfile.get(...)
```

the right one with

```
in1d(...)
```

Comment: can you post a print() of the lists? like a snippet? A good way to avoid this error is to loop through iterables (lists, tuples, etc) like so: for item in iterable: or for i, item in enumerate(iterable): if you need the indexes. This lets python handle the amount if iterations according to the iterable size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually don`t have a problem with getting the indices, but later in the code I use:         a=[val[idx[sb],:] for sb, val in enumerate(idx) if sb in range(len(c))] .       Here I get the error: IndexError: too many indices for array. I think that is due to the different size representation.

Comment: Addition:  I only get the error if I use idx (right List) in enumerate but not if I use Annotatio_Matrix (left List)

Comment: well, a = [val[idx[sb],:] for sb, val in enumerate(idx) if sb in range(len(c))] does not make much sense.. ☺ first of all, idx[sb] = val since val are the items of idx and sb is the index. Can you do val[val] ? Probably not.

Comment: True that. I reused this from before where I needed to reach certain rows in matrices where the matrices where list elements. Now I just want to hand the values from. AS you are right I have to use Annotation_Matrix, as the values are stored in Annotation_Matrix while idx are the indices of Annotation_Matrix I want ot hand over to a.

Comment: if you are not quite sure what is going on, try to avoid list comprehensions. Use explicit for loops instead, gain an understanding and then optionally switch to comprehensions for compactness. Add a couple of print() requests to make sure things are what you assume they are.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will do as you recommend as I switch just recently from Matlab to python. I am still thinking in Matlab logic. Quite confusing some times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array A of size (x,1) is a matrix of x rows and 1 columns (2 dimensions), which differs from A.T of size (1,x). They have the same elements but in different 'orientation'.
An array B of size (x,) is a vector of x coordinates (1 dimension), without any orientation (it's not a row nor a column). It's just a list of elements.

In the first case, one can access an element with A[i,:] which is the same of A[i,0] (because it has only one column).
In the later, the call B[i,:] causes an error because the array B has only one dimension. The correct call is B[i].

I hope this helps you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. To make it 100% clear numpy write (x,1) as only (x,)? As seen in the right picture. But what is then the difference to the left prictrue which says (x,1)?

Comment: Numpy manages both types of arrays: two dimensionals (x,1) and one dimensionals (x,). This is a difference with MATLAB or Octave, in which all are matrices (in this case, only (x,1)).

Comment: Ahhh, Cheers for info. If I use idx=[transpose(idx[sb])for sb in range(len(selected_babies))]  it actually doesn`t change. Shouldn`t it?

Comment: In this case, I don't know what are you doing because I don't see all the variables, but "transposing a 1-D array returns an unchanged view of the original array", as is noted [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html).

Comment: mm. Ok. In Matlab transposing a=a' changes a array form (x,1) to (1,x)

Comment: Yes, and it's the same in Numpy with (x,1) arrays. But with (x,) arrays, transposing doesn't change anything.